# Jquery Get Text of Nested Selector not child

Tags: javascript, jquery

How To Access keyword-text e.g java On click keyword-remove class.

First Of all it's outside keyword-remove scope can not use `$(this)`.
I want to access nested selector span text.

```
<span class="keyword">
  <span class="keyword-remove"></span>
  <span class="keyword-text">java</span>
</span>

$(document).on("click",".keyword-remove", function(){

});
```

Comment: Hi @Zubair, can you elaborate your question

Comment: so select the next sibling

Comment: onclick perform on keyword-remove class,then how to get text (java) from nested selector(span).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `click` event is on the `span`, it cannot be empty. If it is empty you cannot click it. After entering some data in the span select the `sibling` `span` using the `siblings` function and print the `textContent`. Alternatively `.next` can be used instead of `siblings`

```js
$(document).on("click",".keyword-remove", function(){
   console.log($(this).siblings('span')[0].textContent)
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="keyword"><span class="keyword-remove">First span </span><span class="keyword-text">java</span></span>
```

Comment: weird that you mix jquery and non jquery

Answer (score 1):

use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next sibling of the element you clicked.

```js
$(document).on("click",".keyword-remove", function(){
  console.log($(this).next('.keyword-text').text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="keyword">
  <span class="keyword-remove">REMOVE</span>
  <span class="keyword-text">java</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code block -

```
$(document).on("click",".keyword-remove", function(){
  console.log($(this).next().find('.keyword-text').text())
});
```

Working Example - 
https://jsfiddle.net/0wmnxdrp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use `closest()` paired with a following `find()`.  The reason being, this removes the positional logic from the equation, and you only rely on the parent child relationship.

```js
$(document).on("click",".keyword-remove", function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('.keyword').find('.keyword-text').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="keyword">
  <span class="keyword-remove">X</span>
  <span class="keyword-text">java</span>
</span>
```